# php save textarea to file

Tags: php, file, directory, save

I'm trying to remake the script to save the phone configurations to the server. I have a script that generates configs and displays their name and code on the page.

It looks like this:

```
<br>File:112233445566.cfg<br><textarea rows="50" cols="100">#!version:1.0.0.1
#File header "#!version:1.0.0.1" can not be edited or deleted.#
account.1.enable = 1
account.1.label = 123
account.1.display_name = 123
account.1.auth_name = 123
</textarea>
<br>File:112233445566.xml<br/><textarea rows="50" cols="100"><xxxIPPhoneDirectory>
</xxxIPPhoneDirectory>
</textarea><br/>`
```

How do I save the information I received in textarea in two different files with different names (File:xxxxxx.xxx) in the folder on the server?

https://pastebin.com/wSrfQGCt Code of original file

https://pastebin.com/9uqkRPmv Result page in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try submitting the form with textarea and then:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['name_you_give_to_first_textarea']) && isset($_POST['name_you_give_to_second_textarea'])){

        #First file
        $handler = fopen('path/to/folder/file1.txt', 'w+'); #this creates the file if it doesn't exist
        $file1 = fwrite($handler, $_POST['name_you_give_to_first_textarea']);
        fclose($handler);

        #Second file
        $handler = fopen('path/to/folder/file2.txt', 'w+'); #this creates the file if it doesn't exist
        $file2 = fwrite($handler, $_POST['name_you_give_to_second_textarea']);
        fclose($handler);
    }
}
```